# How do I print my Training and Testing ( Accuracy, Validation accuracy) from a saved model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

am new to Deep Learning and I want to get my model's training (accuracy,val_accuracy) and testing (accuracy,val_accuracy) and also I want to know how to print precision, recall and f1-score values with confusion matrix.

here is some details of my model

```
vgg_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
for layer in vgg_model.layers:
       layer.trainable = False
my_vgg_model = Sequential()
my_vgg_model.add(vgg_model)
my_vgg_model.add(Flatten())
my_vgg_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
my_vgg_model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
my_vgg_model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
my_vgg_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
hist = my_vgg_model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
                    batch_size=32, 
                    epochs=1, 
                    verbose=1, 
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                    callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

I haven't tried anything since I am unable to get these training and testing accuracy separately :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After training, loss and accuracy for train and test sets are stored in the hist variable. You can access them as a dictionary by calling `hist.history`.

For other metrics you can go with `sklearn.metrics` as follows:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, precision_score, recall_score, confusion_matrix


# model
vgg_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
for layer in vgg_model.layers:
       layer.trainable = False
my_vgg_model = Sequential()
my_vgg_model.add(vgg_model)
my_vgg_model.add(Flatten())
my_vgg_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
my_vgg_model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
my_vgg_model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
my_vgg_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# training
hist = my_vgg_model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
                    batch_size=32, 
                    epochs=1, 
                    verbose=1, 
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                    callbacks=[cp_callback])

# accuracy
accuracy_train = hist.history['accuracy']
accuracy_test = hist.history['val_accuracy']

# predict with model to get other metrics
y_train_pred = my_vgg_model.predict(x_train)
y_test_pred = my_vgg_model.predict(x_test)

# other metrics
f1_train = f1_score(y_train, y_train_pred)
precision_train = precision_score(y_train, y_train_pred)
recall_train = recall_score(y_train, y_train_pred)
confusion_train = confusion_matrix(y_train, y_train_pred)

f1_test = f1_score(y_test, y_test_pred)
precision_test = precision_score(y_test, y_test_pred)
recall_test = recall_score(y_test, y_test_pred)
confusion_test = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_test_pred)
```